# Blank page with json result after form submition with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm tryin to use ajax to login to my web application, but when i submit the login form i get a blank page with json responses, for example on success login i get:

```
{"success":true}
```

On wrong credentials i get:

```
{"fail":true,"errors":"Email or password is incorrect"}
```

And on wrong email or password i get(validation error):

```
{"fail":true,"errors":{"email":["The email field is required."],"password":["The password field is required."]}}
```

My js file contains this piece of code:

```
$('#loginForm').submit('click',function(e){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    })

e.preventDefault();

var formData = $(this).serialize();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $(this).attr("action"),
    dataType: 'json',
    data: formData,
    success: function (data) {
        window.location.replace("localhost:8000");
    },
    error: function (data) {
        $.each(data.errors, function(index,value) {
            var errorDiv = '#'+index+'_error';
            $(errorDiv).html(value);
        });
    }
});
});
```

In my controller i have the login function:

```
public function login(Request $request){
        try{
            $validate = Validator::make($request->all(),[
                'email' => 'required|max:320',
                'password' => 'required|max:150',
                'remember_me' => 'nullable|accepted'
            ]);

        if($validate->fails()){
            return response()->json(array(
                'fail' => true,
                'errors' => $validate->getMessageBag()->toArray()
            ));
        }

        $rememberMe = $request->remember_me ? true : false;

        if(Sentinel::authenticate(['username'=>$request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $rememberMe)){
            return response()->json(array(
                'success' => true
            ));
        }
        elseif(Sentinel::authenticate(['email'=>$request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $rememberMe)){
            return response()->json(array(
                'success' => true
            ));
        }
        else{
            return response()->json(array(
                'fail' => true,
                'errors' => 'Email or password is incorrect'
            ));
        }
    }
    catch(ThrottlingException $e) {
        $delay = $e->getDelay();

        return redirect('/')->with('error',"After too many login attempts\n you've banned for $delay seconds!");
    }
    catch(NotActivatedException $e) {
        return redirect('/')->with('error','Your account is not activated!');
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        return redirect('/')->with('error',$e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Form:

```
{{ FORM::open(['url' => 'loginua','id'=>'loginForm']) }}
<div class="input-container">
    {{ FORM::text('email', null, ['placeholder' => 'E-mail or Username','id'=>'email', 'autofocus' => 'autofocus','required' => 'required']) }}
    <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
    <div id="#email_error"></div>
</div>
<div class="input-container">
    {{ FORM::password('password', ['placeholder' => 'Password','id' => 'password', 'required' => 'required']) }}
    <i class="fa fa-unlock"></i>
    <div id="#email_error"></div>
</div>
<div class="input-container">
    <label>
        <span class="radio">
            {{ FORM::checkbox('remember_me')}}
            <span class="radio-value" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </span>
        <span>Remember me</span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="input-container">
    {{ FORM::submit('Sign in',['class' => 'btn-style', 'name' => 'sign_in','id'=>'sign_in']) }}
</div>
<div class="user-box-footer">
    <p>Dont have account?<br><a href="{{url('register')}}">Sign up as User</a></p>
    <p><a href="{{url('recovery')}}">Lost password?</a></p>
    <p id="0_error"></p>
</div>
{{ FORM::close() }}
```

Route:

```
Route::post('loginua', 'PagesController@login');
```

I don't know why the jquery on success or fail isn't triggered. Thanks in advance!

Comment: please add your routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem were with the meta tag at the view file, i had to add this line of code to correspond to the ajaxSetup:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{csrf_token()}}"/>
```

Thanks everyone for tips.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('#loginForm').on('submit',function(e){
```

instead of

```
$('#loginForm').submit('click',function(e){
```

Comment: No changes, same result.

Comment: use url: '/loginua', in ajax call and remove 'url' => 'loginua'  from Form::open()

Comment: Without url at the FORM::open() i get MethodNotAllowedHttpException.

Comment: use 'action' => 'PagesController@login' instead and can you check if submit is being triggered by putting alert('something ')  before  $.ajaxSetup

Comment: Looks like the js code isnt being executed, because im not geting any alert .

Comment: wrap all your jquery  in   $(document).ready(function() {  //js code   })  and is there any log in  console?

Comment: Doing so, im getting bunch of errors in the console everytime i click the submit. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Function.each (jquery.js:2)
    at Object.error (login.js:22)
    at j (jquery.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.js:2)
    at x (jquery.js:5)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery.js:5)

Comment: ok so i think  response is now reaching your error section in ajax call but there may be some server side error in your code. check your network tab see response on submit from api call

Comment: The response is the json that is returned from controller.

Comment: There isnt any error on the console, when i don't wrap the code between $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: I'm still getting the response instead of the redirection to index, the blank page isn't what i want, even if there aren't any errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137481/discussion-between-suyog-krazz-and-arlind-hajdari).